# Choosing the right BLDC motor and gearbox

Tags: robotic-arm, torque, motion, bldc

I'm having a trouble understanding how to choose the right BLDC motor and gearbox combo for my final project of engineering school. here are the knowns I have gathered so far:

1. gearbox and motor combo weight needs to be lower than 1 kg.
2. gearbox output 9.55 N.m at 120 RPM (~120W but i'd like to have 180 W ouput abilty to keep a safety factor of 1.5).
3. system voltage, 12 -36 v.
4. the system runs on batteries
5. preferably cheap.

I would be happy to understand how Kv, voltage, internal resistance and max current can help me calculate the output of the motor.

Thanks for the help!